# Passing a String from an HTML input to a python script back out to the webpage using Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am attempting to pass a string from an input in my HTML frontend to a python file/function which contacts google API and then I would like that information spit out back onto the webpage. Right now I can't figure out how to get the function to work. Or, Idk what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my views file

```
from templates.pyfile.pyapi import Api
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Tube
from templates.pyfile import pyapi

# Create your views here.


def tubeView(request):
    search = Tube.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def search(request):
    kw_list = request.POST['content']
    new_search = Tube(content=kw_list)
    new_search.save()
    print(kw_list)
    reApi().main(kw_list)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('home/')
```

Here is my python file

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pad
import time


pytrends = TrendReq()

class Api():
    def main(x):
        self.searchAPI(c)

    def searchAPI(self, kw_list):
        pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 1-m', geo=country_var, gprop='youtube')
        data = pytrends.interest_over_time()
        mean = data.mean()
        print(mean)

        plt.plot(data)
        plt.savefig('Plotzz.png')
        plt.legend(kw_list, loc='upper left')
```

Let me know if you need any other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your input data in `Python` by request for example you have a field in your `HTML` named `q` like this `<input type="text" name="q">` and your form have `method` set to `POST` and `action` is your `Python` function `URL` like this `<form action="{% url 'myfunc' %}" method="POST">`
now when you submit your form then it sends data to given `URL` in `action` so there must be a function in your `Python` which will get all data for you like this

```
def myfunc(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      myquery = request.POST['q']#name of your input tag
      @now do what you want to do with it
   return HttpResponse({'Success':"Done"})
```

and define a url in `urls.py` like this

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('myfunc/',  myfunc, name="myfunc"),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, question tho, I'm assuming myfunc is inside of the views.py folder? Also do I have to use the @ symbol in the function when referring to the class? Thanks

Comment: yes you can write you myfunc in `views.py` or you can create seprate file also

Comment: no you don't have to use `@` symbol inside function to refer class you can initialize your class to a variable like this `a = Myclass()` and then you can access all the attributes of class like this `a.name = "myvalue"`